# How to Vue let input value v-model with v-bind:value operation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Like below code I hope set input2 v-model bind with data-value2,and the value is operationed from value1 * 2, but it does not work and throw error:

> [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
>   v-bind:value="value1*2" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally

```html
<div id="app">
  <input id="input1" type="number" v-model="value1">
  <input id="input2" type="number" v-model="value2" v-bind:value="value1*2">
</div>

<script>
var myObject = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value1: 1,
    value2: 1
  }
})
</script>
```

#### What I've tried:

I can create a onchange method to do it, but it need to duplicate adding `v-on:change="operateValue"` code to input.

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="value1" v-on:change="operateValue">
  <input type="number" v-model="value2" v-on:change="operateValue">
  <input type="number" v-model="value3">
</div>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value1: 1,
    value2: 1,
    value3 : 1
  },
  methods:{
    operateValue:function(){
        app.$data.value3 = (app.$data.value1 * 1 + app.$data.value2 * 1 ) * 2;
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Is it possible? Or I have create a method to custom the operation?

Comment: I've tried it out and it gives me an error

Comment: @PhilipF. yes, it'll throw error,but my expected is like that.

Comment: You need to bind the prop to an object, not an expression.

Comment: please use computed properties

Comment: Ifaruki 、Yom S ,thanks,it's useful for me!

Comment: A quick reminder that posts here need to be written to be as readable as possible, since we try to keep them forever. We want them to be as useful as possible to future readers. With that in mind, please try to observe the rules of English writing, which is that sentences start with a capital letter, and the personal pronoun "I" is always a capital letter. If you are posting on a mobile device, such as a tablet or phone, capital letters can still be produced on an English keyboard.

Comment: @halfer thanks , I'll correct my bad habit.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use v-model and v-bind:value on the same element because it gives you an error.

You can however use a computed property instead:

```js
var myObject = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        value1: 1
    },
    computed: {
        value2: function() {
            return this.value1 * 2;
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <input id="input1" type="number" v-model="value1">
    <input id="input2" type="number" v-bind:value="value2">
    </div>
```

You can then also access 'value2' by using:

```
console.log(myObject.value2);
```

For more infos refer to https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that since `v-model` is just shorthand for `:value="someVar" and`@update="setSomeVar"` what you can do is split them then you should have no problem.

So just write something like above:

```
<input id="input1" type="number" v-model="value1" @input="value2 = $event*2">
<input id="input2" type="number" :value="value2">
```